# how to configure timebased logs and its compression policy

Tags: log4j2

I have a requirement to write log files based on the hour.

Apart from the current log, rest of the logs should be compressed (gz), like below

-rw-r--r-- 1 karthick karthick 58546 Aug 31 19:00 console.20200831-19.log.gz

-rw-r--r-- 1 karthick karthick 58546 Aug 31 20:00 console.20200831-20.log.gz

-rw-r--r-- 1 karthick karthick 58546 Aug 31 21:00 console.20200831-21.log

Tried below snippet, but didn't worked as expected.

```
 <RollingRandomAccessFile
      name="myFile"
      fileName="console.%d{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log" 
      filePattern="console.%d{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log.gz"      
      append="true" immediateFlush="true">  
     <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p %c[1] %m%n">  
     <Policies>         
        <TimeBasedTriggerPolicy>    
     <Policies> 
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have %{d} in the fileName, it is only used to create the target file at rollover. You could leave the fileName attribute off, however you should be aware that the file will not be compressed at shutdown and if the time is different at restart it won't be compressed then either.